# High Availability for MariaDB and Postgres : replication or active-passive (SAN)

Tags: mysql, postgresql, replication, mariadb, high-availability

During the last weeks I did a lot of research on High Availability for Postgres and MariaDB. Both by my own research and also recommended by vendor's, replications seems to have more advantages.

Some benefits as using a standby node for backup; scaling; the fact it is simpler (no need for storage replication) and the flexibility...

However; our own DBA's don't like replication. Our Oracle DBA mentions replication is only useful in addition to clustering.

Is replication a valid (or even better) alternative for active-passive clustering? What do most new HA implementations use?

-- a Linux architect

Answer (score 1):

(Relating to MySQL only...)

In my opinion, a Galera-based solution is the best HA available today.  MariaDB includes Galera in the latest releases; PXC also has it; or you can tack Galera onto Oracle's MySQL.

- "Replication" is an integral part of Galera, but there are low-level differences
- Automatically recovers from single-point-of-failure
- 3 node (server) minimum
- Uses quorum voting to discover what has failed, and avoid "split-brain"
- If the 3 nodes are in 3 different datacenters, no single natural disaster can take out the 'system'
- Read scaling (multiple nodes providing such)

Load balancing, proxying requests, etc, are related topics.